# How to send file NodeJS to java

Tags: node.js

I want to send a .jar file through NodeJS to a serverSocket written in Java... Any idea on how to do this? I have researched everywhere but there is nothing uesful on transferring to Java...

Comment: Well have you attempted to do anything first? Have you performed any research?

Comment: yes i have... i have tried readSockets and reading the jar and writing it to a text file but I need to know how to send a file to a listener

Comment: Why are you writing it to a text file? Jars are not text files.

Comment: yeah as a revision i dont need to write to a text file i just have to be able to send that jar to a listener

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not how to go from node js to java, it is how can I send a file in a protocol that both my server and client can understand. For instance (just an example here) if you wrote your java server to host a webserver, you send it a protocol it understands (node js would use GET or POST etc..). Look in the node js docs for tcp... I don't know about the Java side.

Comment: TCP's can only send files to other Node clients i think

Comment: TCP is a universal protocol, it is used to power http, game servers, heaps.

Comment: how would i use it then

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment until now. Hope you wern't holding your breath :) Some quick research would not hurt anyway. This sort of thing can be done many, many ways. You have not been specific, so you could do it via http, sftp, ftp, raw sockets, any way you want. Most are heavily talked about on the internet, eg... http://tinyurl.com/np4c9mr